# Histogram with same frequencies

Tags: python, histogram

I am plotting a[image] histogram, with another set of data, but the frequencies are all 1, no matter how I change the number of bins. I did this with data generated from a normal distribution in the following fashion

```
x=npr.normal(0,2,(1,100))  
    
plt.hist(x,bins=10)
```

and I get the following histogram:

This happens even if I increase the number of simulations to 1000 or 10000.

How do I plot a histogram that displays the bell shape of the normal distribution?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are ploting one histogram for each column of your input array. That is one histogram with 1 value for each of your 100 columns.

```
x=npr.normal(0,2,(1,100))  
plt.hist(x[0],bins=10)
```

will do (note that I am selecting the first (and only) row of x).